# How does QGIS determine how many tiles to fit in a print layout

Tags: qgis

When I create a print layout in QGIS for a certain page size add add my map to the canvas QGIS will render the map on the screen to fit the page for my desired scale.

[image]

What I'd like to know for a given map scale how does QGIS decide how much terrain to fit on the page. What is the relationship between the source map server's tiles (256 pixels each) and the page size i.e. for every mm on the page, how many pixels of a tile does it render in that mm?

Backstory - I'm a developer and I'm creating a web app that allows users to create map printouts. The app displays a canvas in the shape of a particular size of paper. I need to make sure what they see in the browser is what will get rendered on the same size of paper in QGIS. Right now there is a mismatch so knowing how QGIS performs its calculations will help me adjust on the webside.

Comment: You'll need the DPI and the width or height of the map then the maths is easy